# Load UITableView with images?

Tags: objective-c

I am so lost in this, and have tried everything, now i am having images from the AssetsLibrary, and i want to display them in a matrix on a UITableView, **progrematiclly**  and i dont know how to start.

i would be happy to get a direction on how to link my UIImages to a tableView( i need code..) and create him in a matrix .
please, give me any direction ..

this is how i get the images from the assetsLibrary :

```
//------ get the images from the camera roll ----------
    NSMutableArray *cameraRollPictures=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSInteger numberOfAssets = [group numberOfAssets];
        if (numberOfAssets > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"numberOfPictures: %d",numberOfAssets);
            //NSInteger lastIndex = numberOfAssets - 1;
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= numberOfAssets-1; i++)
            {
                [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
                 {
                    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
                    //NSLog(@"theObject!!!! -- (%d) %@",i,thumbnail);
                    [cameraRollPictures addObject:thumbnail];
                }];
            }
        }

    }
      failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
```

EDIT:

any idea why i get in the for loop every image twice ? it logs each index 2 times ..

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) how images matrix is created

If you want to create a matrix of image look also [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker)

Or [here](https://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController)

Comment: thanks i am looking into this. the UITableView is not my friend ??

Comment: Thanks. I was getting duplicates and fist link helped. In enumeration I added `if (group)` statement.